# prevent scrolling behind a fixed position element

Tags: html, css

I have a footer fixed at the bottom of my page with a set height. Is it possible to scroll the content of my page such that it ends at the top of the fixed footer?

A fiddle of my issue here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9wrmhxp/)

The last 250px (the footer height) of non-fixed elements scroll behind the footer and aren't seen when the scrollbar hits the bottom of the page.

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 50%; background-color: yellow;"></div>
<div style="height: 500px; width: 50%; background-color: blue;"></div>
<div style="height: 500px; width: 50%; background-color: green;"></div>

<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 250px; bottom: 0; background-color: #ccc;">
  Fixed Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you will need to do, however you need to write CSS and would be good if you write CSS separately instead of giving style properties to div.

> In order to fix your problem we need to set overflow to be hidden
>   Learn more about these properties [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

```css
body,
html{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; width: 50%; background-color: yellow;"></div>
<div style="height: 500px; width: 50%; background-color: blue;"></div>
<div style="height: 500px; width: 50%; background-color: green;"></div>

<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 250px; bottom: 0; background-color: #ccc;">
  Fixed Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a margin-bottom of 250px on the last DIV

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 50%; background-color: green; margin-bottom:250px;">
</div>
```